# Access is denied when trying to AcquireTokenInteractive for Azure Public Client App

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am calling Graph API from my Bot service and everything works fine when I am working on localhost, but after deployment to Azure app service I have started to get Access is denied exception when trying to use AcquireTokenInteractive. I have also setup App registration for this app with all necessary permissions to call Graph API, however it didn't help.
My code looks like this:

````
authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
.WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
.WithPrompt(Microsoft.Identity.Client.Prompt.SelectAccount)
.ExecuteAsync();```
````

Comment: Seems you might be missing some azure credentials configuration on your Azure app service?

Comment: Have you added your connection information in appsettings.json to your Azure  bot? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#bot-authentication-msgraph-example

Comment: By connection information you mean app id and app secret? If yes, then I have them setup correctly. I had an idea that it might be some problem in my MSTeams App Manifest?